# FFmpeg downmuxing multiple tracks with custom "af"s

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to do a custom downmix conversion, that is the rough equivalent of :

```
ffmpeg -y -i "file.mkv" \
 -map 0:1 -c:0 flac -ac:0 4 \
 -map 0:3 -c:1 flac -ac:1 3 \
 -map 0:3 -c:2 flac -ac:2 3 \
 audio.mkv
```

I tried using the command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "file.mkv" \
 -map 0:1 -c:0 flac -af:0 "pan=3.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR | FC = FC | LFE = LFE" \
 -map 0:3 -c:1 flac -af:1 "pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC | LFE = LFE" \
 -map 0:3 -c:2 flac -af:2 "pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC + 0.5*LFE | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC  + 0.5*LFE" \
 audio.mkv
```

But it gave an error that only 1 "af" is supported, unlike "ac":

```
Only '-af pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC + 0.5*LFE | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC  + 0.5*LFE | LFE = FC' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters
```

So I tried doing as it said, and separated them with a comma:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "file.mkv" \
 -map 0:1 -c:0 flac \
 -map 0:3 -c:1 flac \
 -map 0:3 -c:2 flac \
 -af "pan=3.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR | FC = FC | LFE = LFE,pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC | LFE = LFE,pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC + 0.5*LFE | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC  + 0.5*LFE | LFE = LFE" \
 audio.mkv
```

Which started the encoding, but I noticed that it was only applying the last pan, and all three tracks were being downmixed to the last 2.1!

According to the documentation, https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1 adding a "," is creating a "filterchain" which I don't think I want, as I am doing the same filter on three different tracks. So I am at a loss of what I am supposed to do from there.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-af` is an old shorthand for `-filter:a` and does not accept stream specifiers. Use `-filter:a:1` for example to assign filters for the 2nd audio output stream.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use `-filter_complex`:

```
ffmpeg -i "file.mkv" -filter_complex \
"[0:1]pan=3.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR | FC = FC | LFE = LFE[a0];
 [0:3]pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC | LFE = LFE[a1];
 [0:3]pan=2.1| FL < FL + 0.6*BL + 0.6*SL + 0.5*FC + 0.5*LFE | FR < FR + 0.6*BR + 0.6*SR + 0.5*FC  + 0.5*LFE[a2]" \
-map "[a0]" -map "[a1]" -map "[a2]" -c:a flac audio.mkv
```